# Unable to install Cryengine 5 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, software-installation, sdl

I am trying to install cryengine 5 on ubuntu 16.04. I am using the source code and sdk provided on their [github repo](https://github.com/CRYTEK-CRYENGINE). This is the compilation command I am using :

```
./cry_waf.sh build_linux_x64_gcc_profile --project-spec=gamesdk
```

All I have done before this is to copy the GameSDK contents into the CryEngine's `root/Code/SDKs` folder.

This is the error I am getting:

```
In file included from /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_3.cpp:5:0:
/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/../../../Code/CryEngine/CryAction/SimpleHttpServer/SimpleHttpServerListener.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void CSimpleHttpServerListener::OnGetRequest(int, string)’:
/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/../../../Code/CryEngine/CryAction/SimpleHttpServer/SimpleHttpServerListener.cpp:251:52: error: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
     fread((char*)page.data(), 1, page.size(), file);
                                                    ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
^[[1;3C
In file included from /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon/CryCore/Assert/CryAssert_impl.h:23:0,
                 from /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon/CryCore/Platform/platform_impl.inl:144,
                 from /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/../../../Code/CryEngine/CryAction/CryAction.cpp:28,
                 from /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_1.cpp:14:
/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon/CryAssert/CryAssert_Linux.h: In function ‘bool CryAssert(const char*, const char*, unsigned int, bool*)’:
/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon/CryAssert/CryAssert_Linux.h:103:37: error: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
   fscanf(assert_file, "%d", &result);
                                     ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Build failed
 -> task in 'cxx (linux_x64_gcc|profile)' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140323113462352: cxx CryAction_main_uber_3.cpp -> CryAction_main_uber_3.cpp.1.o}
'g++ -m64 -Wall -Werror -ffast-math -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-parentheses -Wno-switch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-multichar -Wno-format-security -Wno-empty-body -Wno-comment -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-narrowing -Wno-write-strings -Wno-format -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-reorder -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-overloaded-virtual -O2 -msse2 -MD -g2 -gdwarf-2 -fpic -fpic -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/linux_x64_gcc_profile/_shared/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs/boost -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs/yasli -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/Libs/yasli -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -DCODE_BASE_FOLDER="/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/" -D_PROFILE -DPROFILE -DLINUX -D__linux__ -DLINUX64 -DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR -D_MT -D_DLL -DCRY_FEATURE_SCALEFORM_HELPER -D_USRDLL -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_0=1 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_1=0 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_2=0 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_3=0 /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_3.cpp -c -o /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/linux_x64_gcc_profile/_shared/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_3.cpp.1.o'
 -> task in 'cxx (linux_x64_gcc|profile)' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140323113462288: cxx CryAction_main_uber_1.cpp -> CryAction_main_uber_1.cpp.1.o}
'g++ -m64 -Wall -Werror -ffast-math -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-parentheses -Wno-switch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-multichar -Wno-format-security -Wno-empty-body -Wno-comment -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-narrowing -Wno-write-strings -Wno-format -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-deprecated -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-reorder -Wno-conversion-null -Wno-overloaded-virtual -O2 -msse2 -MD -g2 -gdwarf-2 -fpic -fpic -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/linux_x64_gcc_profile/_shared/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs/boost -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs/yasli -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/Libs/yasli -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryCommon -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs -I/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/CryEngine/CryAction -DCODE_BASE_FOLDER="/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/" -D_PROFILE -DPROFILE -DLINUX -D__linux__ -DLINUX64 -DSWIG_CSHARP_NO_IMCLASS_STATIC_CONSTRUCTOR -D_MT -D_DLL -DCRY_FEATURE_SCALEFORM_HELPER -D_USRDLL -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_0=1 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_1=0 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_2=0 -DEXE_VERSION_INFO_3=0 /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_1.cpp -c -o /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/linux_x64_gcc_profile/_shared/BinTemp/uber_files/CryAction/CryAction_main_uber_1.cpp.1.o'
```

Also, I am getting these warnings and errors:

```
[WARNING] No default compiler found, enabling compiler auto-detection
[WAF] Executing 'build_linux_x64_gcc_profile' in '/home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/BinTemp/linux_x64_gcc_profile/_shared'
[WARNING] /home/cortana/Desktop/CRYENGINE-5.1.1/Code/SDKs/Scaleform not found, this feature is excluded from this build.
[WARNING] NVAPI SDK not found, excluding from the build.
[WARNING] AMD AGS SDK not found, excluding from the build.
MSVC 14.0 is not being used - CryRenderD3D12 cannot be built.
[WARNING] SDL_Mixer binaries missing
[ERROR] Attempting to build CryAudioImplFmod, but could not find the Fmod SDK at Code/SDKs/Audio/fmod, skipping.
[ERROR] Attempting to build CryAudioImplWwise, but could not find the Wwise SDK at Code/SDKs/Audio/AK, skipping.
```

I dont understand why a few of these are coming and how to remove them.
I have g++ installed so the first warning shouldn't be there. For `sdl_mixer`, I installed `libsdl2-dev` and `libsdl2-mixer-dev`, still it says binaries missing. I have downloaded the whole GameSDK from the repository but it still says something is missing. How do I resolve these errors and compile and run the Cryengine?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple! After a lot of searching on internet i found nothing but the answer its on cryengine site but they use (optional). Just open terminal and type

> sudo apt-get install clang

and then put

> ./cry_waf.sh build_linux_x64_clang_profile --project-spec=gamesdk

and not

> ./cry_waf.sh build_linux_x64_gcc_profile --project-spec=gamesdk

I hope I helped you and if my english is bad its just 7th grade english

Comment: Tried it but the same error with `Fmod SDK` and `Wwise SDK` still remains.